# Provide timestamp in message to IoT central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

I want to connect a 'real device' with Azure IoT Central and connect a local source application to it using MQTT. I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-iot-device-mqtt) code for the connection and replace.

However, I cannot find any information on how to provide the timestamp. [This](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911455-azure-iot-central/suggestions/35197819-device-originated-timestamp) thread suggests to set "iothub-creation-time-utc" as a "property" - I am not sure how to do that however. Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the property to the message:

```
message.properties.add('iothub-creation-time-utc', utcDT);
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the links in your question I assume you are using Node.js to develop your device code. There is a sample code snippet that shows how to set the creation time property here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-connecting-pi-node

```
function sendTelemetry(data, schema) {
  if (deviceOnline) {
    var d = new Date();
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var message = new Message(payload);
    message.properties.add('iothub-creation-time-utc', d.toISOString());
    message.properties.add('iothub-message-schema', schema);

    console.log('Sending device message data:\n' + payload);
    client.sendEvent(message, printErrorFor('send event'));
  } else {
    console.log('Offline, not sending telemetry');
  }
}
```