# How to use a custom timestamp property in IoT Central charts X axis

Tags: azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-central

On an IoT Central app, is there a way to use a custom timestamp property on the X axis of the charts displayed on the dashboards?

Here's a picture of some sample raw data: [Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Y2D.png)

```
{
 "_eventcreationtime": "2022-09-05T18:05:18.316Z",
 "Controller": {
     "Temperature4K_1": 71.468,
     "Temperature4K_2": 61.428,
     "Temperature40K_1": 39.135,
     "Temperature40K_2": 32.69,
     "TelemetryMagnetID": "Ex accusamus non commodi id ab excepturi facere et.",
     "Timestamp": "2023-01-07T19:50:11.189Z" **<- I want to use this Timestamp as the X Axis**
 },
 "_eventtype": "Telemetry",
 "_timestamp": "2022-09-05T18:05:18.369Z" **<- Looks like the the charts always use this timestamp on X Axis**
}
```

I would like to use the **Controller.Timestamp** as the value to be used on the X axis of the charts, but it looks like the **_timestamp** is always used.

If this is the case is there a way to set the Controller.Timestamp property has another system property before the message is sent by the device (using the C# IoT Device SDK) so that I can use the value of the source Timestamp on the X axis of the charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer just in case others need this information.

After reaching out to Microsoft support, I got the following answer:

> You can use the "iothub-creation-time-utc" property in message
> properties to set the source timestamp. If this property is set,
> IoTCentral will use the timestamp value of this field for
> dashboards/charts. If the property is not set, IoTCentral will use the
> enqueued time.

So adding the code below addressed my question:

```
message.properties.add('iothub-creation-time-utc', timestamp);
```

There's also a related question here: [Provide timestamp in message to IoT central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243977/provide-timestamp-in-message-to-iot-central)